# Get information from listview in Android

Tags: android, listview

I am inserting to ListView 3 variables, but I am showing only 2. The KEY_NAME and KEY_SUM and it working OK. I am also putting 3rd variable KEY_WIK that I do not wish the user to see. How can get the KEY_WIK when user clicks the value?

```
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                    menuItems, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                    new String[] { "KEY_NAME", "KEY_SUM", "KEY_WIK" }, new int[] {
                            android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

                    String GName = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).getText().toString();
                    String GSum = ((TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2)).getText().toString();
                    //String GWik = ?

                }

            });
```

Comment: `final Map<String, ?> the_clicked_element_from_menuItems = (Map<String, ?>)arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);` wheeee!!! for rest of "properties use the same object (not getText() from TextView)

Comment: `HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) arg0.getItemAtPosition(position);
                   String s = map.get("KEY_WIK");`

Answer (score -2):

```
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                menuItems, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2,
                new String[] { "KEY_NAME", "KEY_SUM", "KEY_WIK" }, new int[] {
                        android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position, long arg3) {

                String GWik = arg0.getItemAtPosition(position); 

            }

        });
```

Comment: WRONG!!! ... getItemAtPosition return Object (where are my downvotes when i need 'em? **edit:** i did find one :) )